# Third party tool ecs-deploy getting error while deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have installed thrid party tool  `pip install ecs-deploy` from https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy When I try to deploy `ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service` I am getting some error

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-32-82-233 ~]$ ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ecs", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3033, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3062, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 863, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (botocore 1.12.92 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('botocore<1.15.0,>=1.14.9'), set(['boto3']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled aws-cli and installed again by taking reference of this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-linux.html. It worked